# Problem with plastic collision

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, collision

An object with a mass **m_1=2kg** is moving onto smooth horizontal ground collides perfectly and inelastically with an another with a mass **m_2**. If the Kinetic energy at start was **18J** and the energy loss during the collision was **15J**,what is the mass of m_2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two hints:

1. In any collision, whether it is elastic or inelastic, momentum is conserved i.e. momentum after the collision must equal momentum before the collision.
2. In a perfectly inelastic collision the final velocities of the two objects are the same i.e. you can think of them as being stuck together after the collision.